# How to do base64 encoding for login service in angular js

Tags: java, angularjs, restful-authentication

Can anyone suggest a best way to do encoding for login credentials in angular js?
I don't want to sent username and password directly in post request.
How to handle this if we are using java restful webservice in server side to validate the credentials against DB.

Comment: Base64 is an encoding, not encryption.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) for this.

> HTTPS is a protocol for secure communication over a computer
>   network which is widely used on the Internet. HTTPS consists of
>   communication over Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) within a
>   connection encrypted by Transport Layer Security or its predecessor,
>   Secure Sockets Layer. The main motivation for HTTPS is authentication
>   of the visited website and protection of the privacy and integrity of
>   the exchanged data.

Comment: Do you know how to do encryption for username and password before we sending it to restful web service as a post request in https?

Comment: @SmartGeek do you have some specific question about the encryption? Otherwise your question is to broad to answer.

Comment: HTTPS is doing this for you. Since your client code is public you cannot use any symmetric encryption without publishing your key. Making it useless. Implementing asymmetric encryption yourself would mean you are reinventing what HTTPS is doing for you.